# doGet() cannot get any data from model

Tags: java, servlets

I have a simple servlet app. In the servlet class, `doPost()` and `doGet()` basically get the same data from model class, however, `doGet()` cannot get any data.

```
public class ClickerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    ClickerModel clickerModel = new ClickerModel();

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String servletPath = request.getServletPath();

        if (servletPath.equals("/submit")) {
            doPost(request, response);
        } else if (servletPath.equals("/getResults")) {
            doGet(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String answer = request.getParameter("answer");
        clickerModel.addAnswer(answer);

        request.setAttribute("recentAnswer", clickerModel.getRecentAnswer());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("submit.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("ok" + clickerModel.getRecentAnswer());
        request.setAttribute("clickerModel", clickerModel);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("results.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

My `ClickerModel` class:

```
public class ClickerModel {

    private String recentAnswer;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> answers;

    public ClickerModel() {
        recentAnswer = "";
        answers = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addAnswer(String answer) {
        recentAnswer = answer;

        if (answers.containsKey(answer)) {
            answers.put(answer, answers.get(answer) + 1);
        } else {
            answers.put(answer, 1);
        }
    }

    public void clearAnswers() {
        answers = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public String getRecentAnswer() {
        return recentAnswer;
    }
}
```

Anyone knows why I cannot get any data from model using `doGet()`? Thanks!

For more information:

`doPost()` is called from a form submission.

```
<form action="submit" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A"> A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B"> B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C"> C<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D"> D<br>
    <br><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

`doGet()` is called when I directly paste and hit the url (`localhost:something/getResults`) in the browser.

And my `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Results</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Clicker.ClickerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Results</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/getResults</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Submit</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Clicker.ClickerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Submit</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/submit</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: How do you call your servlet?

Comment: @Jens I have updated the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my understanding, that you place the doGet() method in Results servlet, not same as Submit one.

Submit Servlet:

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String answer = request.getParameter("answer");
        clickerModel.addAnswer(answer);

        request.setAttribute("recentAnswer", clickerModel.getRecentAnswer());
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("submit.jsp").forward(request, response);  
    response.sendRedirect("getResults"); //   <---After submit will go to this page. 
    }
```

Results Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("ok" + clickerModel.getRecentAnswer());
    request.setAttribute("clickerModel", clickerModel);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("results.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```